# Whats the best way to deal with "dead / unused" branches in GIT?

Tags: git

in our project we use GIT as SCM. As usal we create seperate branches for new features, complex bugfixes, next version etc. . When (e.g.) a new features are fully implemented they are merged into master which is our "next version" branch (and is merged into trunk and live during later testing / deploying). So after a new feature branch is merged into master it's "dead". At the moment I delete the "dead" branches to keep the branchlist small and cleary. But as I noticed at the last delete I do this at the cost of loosing the branchs history.

My question now is: Whats the best way to deal with "dead" branches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say that branches *that have been merged* to master, i.e. listed by

```
git branch --merged
```

can and should be safely deleted with

```
git branch -d <merged_branch>
git push --delete origin <merged_branch>
```

One of the points of Git is that it is so easy to create (and merge) branches. You should "branch early and often". But to let all those old deleted branches lie around is messy. The important historical information is in the commits and their relationships to each other.

Remember that the auto generated message for a merge commit contains the name of the branch. So there is normally no problem in determining the original branch name (in case it contained some interesting information).

Branches that have not been merged are another matter:

```
git branch --no-merged
```

They cannot be deleted with `-d`, but must be deleted with `-D`, so it's hard to do by mistake. Personally, I eventually delete those too, but I wait a *lot* longer.

Comment: As written in my question I'm doing exactly this, so (as long as no more answers are written) I think my behavoir is not as bad as I thought in between. But please understand that I don't accept your answer right now. Perhaps someone else has other opinions/arguments/workflows. But thank you very much!

Comment: Last command should read  `git branch --no-merged` (removed one hyphen)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I like to make a copy of a branch so that I can squash the commits before I merge onto the master.  This means that the master branch will have much fewer commit and the history is simpler.

I will then delete the squashed branch and keep the original branch so that I have a more detailed history stored on my local machine. At this point I would recommend tagging the branch to say that it does not need to be merged onto master (merging would not have any effect).

```
git tag -a s1 -m "this branch was squash into <squash commit> on master"
```

Mercurial allows you to mark branches as dead so that they cannot be merged onto master.